# What really happened to Zatanna during her fight with Felix Faust?

Tags: character, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-dark

In *Justice League Dark*, Zatanna was able to cancel Felix Faust's magic to stop women from talking in his house by removing cloth from the statue. But after that Zatanna just lost control and she almost killed Felix Faust in an attack but Constantine stops her.

Even Felix Faust admits that he is afraid of her. And when she lost control she looks like possessed. I have seen many Zatanna adaptations from DCAU to Young Justice but never noticed her being that powerful and offensive before.

So, What really happened to her? Is this part taken from some comics?

Answer (score 2):

> Throughout Justice League Dark, Zatanna is shown to be a very powerful magic user. However, through her conversations with Constantine, we learn that she is afraid to explore her full potential. In DC comics, when a magic user taps into an energy source, it contains both divine and evil magic. If the person tapping into the magic doesn't know how to control the dark side, it can consume them, and their soul will be lost.

Taken from [moviepilot](https://moviepilot.com/p/justice-league-dark-movie-dcau-dceu/4196028)

Zatanna basically tapped into her magic full force and lost control. Hopes this helps.

Comment: Can you back up your claim from the comics?